# Ultrafilters voting system counter example

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, limits

I know that we can view ultrafilters as a counter to Arrows' theorem. See for example https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/25/ultrafilters-nonstandard-analysis-and-epsilon-management/

or https://pleasantfeeling.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/arrowstheorem/

In the first link where it talks about the usual limit properties, i'm not quite following the logic of how we get that if the sequence (0,1,0,1,...) has a limit of x. Then by algebra homomorphism it follows x^2 = x. (Is this because we can view 0 as one convergent sequence and 1 as the other). Also I don't quite follow how to get that (1,0,1,0...) has a limit 1-x.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
1,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

If this sequence converges to $x$ in some notion of convergence that obeys the algebra homomorphism law, then the sequence $\langle a_n^2:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ must converge to $x^2$. But $a_n^2=a_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so of course $\langle a_n^2:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$, and therefore $x^2=x$, which implies that $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Now let $b_n=1$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. The constant sequence $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ certainly converges to $1$. Let

$$c_n=b_n-a_n=1-a_n=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
0,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $\langle c_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle 1,0,1,0,\ldots\rangle$, and

$$\lim_nc_n=\lim_n(b_n-a_n)=\lim_nb_n-\lim_na_n=1-x\;.$$

However, it’s easy to see that $c_n=a_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so if our notion of limit obeys the shift invariance law, $\langle c_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle a_{n+1}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ must have the same limit as $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, namely, $x$. Thus, if our limit obeys those two laws, we must have $1-x=x$, which is of course false if $x=0$ or $x=1$.

This shows that the sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ cannot be assigned a limit that

- is compatible with the usual notion of limit for convergent sequences, and
- obeys the algebra homomorphism and shift invariance laws.